# How to manage browser back button in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am working on ADF project. In which Dynamic Region and Bounded Task flow has been using. Now I have a requirement if Back button of browser in clicked then user should log out and land on Login.jsf page again.
For this task I have read one article "http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-handle-web-browser-buttons-in.html" and tried to do the same thing. 
I was able to pop up the alert window successfully. But when i click on Leave Page then it does not send the navigation to Login.jsf page. 
Please let me know how to manage the confirm box event.

Comment: You cannot do this - there is no browser API to alter behavior of the back button. Do not break the back button. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42392/does-dont-break-the-back-button-apply-to-web-applications  There are alternative approaches that provide a better user-experience.

Comment: what are the alternative approaches? can you share some resources with me?

Answer (score 0):

Your web-application should not return HTML for a POST request unless there were errors/issues with the data being submitted, after a successful POST request the web-application should issue a HTTP 3xx response, that way the Back/Forward buttons will not trigger a POST resubmit.

If you're working with a multi-page form, such as a wizard or other workflow, then your web-application should maintain full state during the user's transaction and explicitly support "time travel" in the user's workflow. If a user presses the back button and a previous-step page is loaded, then a resubmission of that step should cause the entire workflow's state to be updated. Data must not be actually committed until the entire workflow is complete. If your application cannot conform to this model then you have other issues at-hand.

I do not have any experience with Oracle's platform, but I imagine these scenarios are possible given this is fairly standard and expected behavior.

...however, logging the user out when pressing the back button is just downright bad UX.